# javafx ActionListener for CheckBoxTableCell

Tags: java, javafx, callback, observable, observablelist

I tried both solutions of this question here :[JavaFX: CheckBoxTableCell get ActionEvent when user check a checkBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671132/javafx-checkboxtablecell-get-actionevent-when-user-check-a-checkbox)

The first solution did not work for me but at least my IDE compiled.
The 2nd solution tells me :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
>   `ObservableList<new Callback<TaskControl,Observable[]>(){}>` to `ObservableList<TaskControl>`

```
import javafx.util.Callback;
public ObservableList<TaskControl> obsTasks;

obsTasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Callback<TaskControl, Observable[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable[] call(final TaskControl param) {
                        return new Observable[]{param.getIsDone()};
                    }
                });
```

My TaskControl.getIsDone() function:

```
public final BooleanProperty getIsDone() {
        return isDone;
    }
```

Would be great if I could get that part to compile so I can continue.

Thanks.

Comment: That compiles fine for me. Check you have the correct import for `Observable` (`javafx.beans.Observable`).

Comment: That solved it. Thanks you very much!