# CheckBoxTableCell: change Cursor when clicked

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a `TableView` with a `CheckBoxTableCell` column.

I would like to catch the selection of the cell and change the Cursor to `Cursor.WAIT`.

Clicking the cell will cause some db-query to happen, that will take a few seconds. I would like to notify  the user that something is going on and the application did not just die.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<IOrigin, Boolean> cActive;

@Override
public void initialize(final URL location, final ResourceBundle resources) {
cActive.setCellFactory(tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
[..]

}
```

Listening on `CheckBoxTableCell#selectedProperty()` does not work, it does not fire any change events.

The column cells are bound to a bean property via fxml.

```
<TableColumn text="Active" editable="true" fx:id="cActive">
<cellValueFactory>
<PropertyValueFactory property="active" />
/cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

Comment: What does `updateItem(...)` have to do with selection?

Comment: Nothing, but this one I could override respectively change the cursor before and after. But when this method is called, all the work is already done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274939/javafx-how-do-i-trigger-an-event-if-someone-check-a-checkbox-in-tableview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX: CheckBoxTableCell get ActionEvent when user check a checkBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671132/javafx-checkboxtablecell-get-actionevent-when-user-check-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

[With the cells show CheckBox in TableView:](http://o7planning.org/en/11079/javafx-tableview-tutorial)

- Note that the CheckBoxTableCell renders the CheckBox 'live', meaning that the CheckBox is always interactive and can be directly toggled by the user.
- This means that it is not necessary that the cell enter its editing state (usually by the user double-clicking on the cell).
- A side-effect of this is that the usual editing callbacks (such as on edit commit) will not be called.
- If you want to be notified of changes, it is recommended to directly observe the boolean properties that are manipulated by the CheckBox.

Comment: I understand. But observing "the boolean properties that are manipulated.." means observing the model object for a UI task. That is a bit smelly and will require major refactorings so the "scene" object is available to the model.