# JavaFx Tableview how to add a listener to checkbox column

Tags: javafx, checkbox, tableview, listener, addition

I'm just starting to work with JavaFX. I create a TableView with 3 columns, (name, last name and select). This last is a Checkbox column. this is my code:

PersonTableController.java:

```
package ch.makery.sortfilter;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;


/**
 * View-Controller for the person table.
 * 
 * @author Marco Jakob
 */
public class PersonTableController {

    @FXML
    private TextField filterField;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> selectColumn; 

    private ObservableList<Person> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Just add some sample data in the constructor.
     */
    public PersonTableController() {
        masterData.add(new Person("Hans", "Muster"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Ruth", "Mueller"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Heinz", "Kurz"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Cornelia", "Meier"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Werner", "Meyer"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Lydia", "Kunz"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Anna", "Best"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Stefan", "Meier"));
        masterData.add(new Person("Martin", "Mueller"));
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     * 
     * Initializes the table columns and sets up sorting and filtering.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // 0. Initialize the columns.
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        selectColumn.setCellValueFactory(     
                 new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("select")
        );  

        // 1. Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
        FilteredList<Person> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(masterData, p -> true);

        // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
        filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
                // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }

                // Compare first name and last name of every person with filter text.
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if (person.getFirstName().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true; // Filter matches first name.
                } else if (person.getLastName().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true; // Filter matches last name.
                }
                return false; // Does not match.
            });
        });

        // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
        SortedList<Person> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

        // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
        //    Otherwise, sorting the TableView would have no effect.
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(personTable.comparatorProperty());

        // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
        personTable.setItems(sortedData);
    }
}
```

Person.java:

```
    package ch.makery.sortfilter;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;

/**
 * Simple model class for the person table.
 * 
 * @author Marco Jakob
 */
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private CheckBox selec = new CheckBox();    

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);     
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public CheckBox getSelect() {
        return select;
    }

    public void setSelect(CheckBox select) {
        this.select = select;
    }
}
```

PersonTable.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane minWidth="315.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="315.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ch.makery.sortfilter.PersonTableController">
  <children>
    <TableView fx:id="personTable" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
      <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="firstNameColumn" maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="First Name" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="lastNameColumn" maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Last Name" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="selectColumn" maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Select" />
      </columns>
<columnResizePolicy>
<TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
</columnResizePolicy>
    </TableView>
    <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
      <children>
        <Label text="Filter Table:" />
        <TextField fx:id="filterField" prefWidth="-1.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I want than just one person can be selected at the time, so try unsuccessfully to add a event or listener to do that. If any checkbox is checked and user check one of them, is OK. But if one checkbox is checked and other checkbox is checked at same time, then the first one must to be unchecked, just like RadioButton works.

Some one can help me?

Best regards

Comment: You're starting from the wrong place. You shouldn't have UI elements (`CheckBox`) in your data model (`Person`). See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671132/javafx-checkboxtablecell-get-actionevent-when-user-check-a-checkbox/28671914 for how to use `CheckBox` in the *cells* of a table.

Comment: Thank you James_D for answer. i will try to follow the example

Comment: Once you have made those changes, you can just handle the "select only one at a time" functionality via the model; it doesn't need to involve the table at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @James_D.

finally I can implement the "just-one" checkbox selection. I followed the example than you show me:

[javafx-checkboxtablecell-get-actionevent-when-user-check-a-checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671132/javafx-checkboxtablecell-get-actionevent-when-user-check-a-checkbox/28671914)

And I add this code to call event:

```
checkedCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, 
ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {
            System.out.println("Cours "+coursData.get(param).getCours()+" changed value to " +coursData.get(param).isChecked());
            for (Integer i = 0; i < coursData.size(); i++) {
                if (i != param && coursData.get(param).isChecked()) {
                    coursData.get(i).setChecked(false);
                } // if
            } //  for
            return coursData.get(param).checkedProperty();
        }
    }));
```

in for cicle, I uncheck the rest of checkboxes in table.

Thank you very much for help.

Best Regards.

Leo.