# Java - incorrect action at selecting a checkbox

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox

I work on Java FX.
I have a tableview in which I created a "select checkbox" column. The goal is when a user clicks on a checkbox, an alert message appears.
To test it, I first tried to display a System.out.println message.
The problem are :

- when I only select one checkbox, I have a System.out.println message that writes all the checkboxes :

> ```
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@34752060
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@654bd7bc
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@74bbebe0
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@2e23be4f
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@3348edcb
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@8052a29
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@23ca3422
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@102837d2
> com.calculatrice.app.model.Person@647ab6a9
> ```

- when I select nothing, I have the same System.out.println message

How could I do to have a message with item(s), corresponding to the checkbox(es) selected ?

Here is my snippet :

```
  private void selectCheckBox(ActionEvent ae) {
         // personTable is the Tableview ; Person is the class where the getter is declared
        for(Person p : personTable.getItems()){
            if (p.getSelect().isSelected()){
                System.out.println (p + " is selected");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I think overriding the `toString` method will help solve this problem. Well, I guess it's not really a problem because it's expected behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Could I ask you how to make it ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I don’t know what your implementation is,  but if the selected field on Person is not a full BooleanProperty and you aren’t using [CheckboxTableCell](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html), you probably should be.  You may also have other issues in the code we cannot see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX: CheckBoxTableCell get ActionEvent when user check a checkBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671132/javafx-checkboxtablecell-get-actionevent-when-user-check-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

You could label the checkboxes then use `getLabel` to get their name.

```
        if (p.getSelect().isSelected()){
            System.out.println (p.getLabel() + " is selected");
        }
```

Alternatively, if you don't want visible labels, you can use `setName` and `getName`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I still see the same behaviour. When I select one checkbox, the message returns the labels of every checkbox.

Comment: i'm just guessing but the problem could be in the internal implementation of the Person class

Comment: Also if you are using bindings, make sure you bind and unbind them at appropriate times. When I started with javafx I would end up with 100 things bound to one control.